# Code is not getting scanned after Sonarqube Azure Devops analysis

Tags: azure, azure-devops, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am using Sonarqube for Azure DevOps pipeline. These are my tasks my pipeline has
[image]

No code is getting scanned for the solution WebService on the sonarqube project. I am using MSBuild for building the code.

[image]

One warning I am getting is this. Though I have visual studio 2019 is installed on the build machine.

`SonarScanner for MSBuild 4.10`
`Fixed invalid Code Analysis ErrorLog file. Please check that VS 2015 Update 1 (or later) is installed. Fixed file: E:\Build Agents\AquilaPool2-Agent-2\_work\15\s\Src\Services\DataIngestion\St\WebService\XWS.WebAPI\bin\WebService.dll.RoslynCA_fixed.json 2020-09-23T08:45:11.5066077Z Fixed invalid Code Analysis ErrorLog file. Please check that VS 2015 Update 1 (or later) is installed. Fixed file`

Comment: What is the version of your Run Code Analysis task? As I know, Sonar Scanner for MSBuild has supported MSBuild v16 since **v4.6**, you could try to remove Sonarqube tasks and re-add them, if you are using Azure devops services not Azure devops Server.

Comment: Run code analysis version is 4.11.0. I fixed the issue by adding `sonar.scm.exclusions.disabled=true` in Prepare analysis on SonarQube step. Thoguh this error is still coming

Comment: Thanks for your quickly reply. Glad to know you have resolved this issue. To be precise, your warnings, not errors, still exist, right?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Yes this `Fixed invalid Code Analysis ErrorLog file` warning is still present in the Run code Analysis step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding `sonar.scm.exclusions.disabled=true` in Prepare analysis on SonarQube step. Though this Roslyn error is still coming. All the files are getting scanned now.